# Javafx component won't show in JFrame for a seond time after dispose

Tags: swing, javafx

My java project has 2 JFrame. Let's call it A and B. Frame A has a button that when click will show Frame B.

In a button's event listener is

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable () {
    public void run() {
        B b = new B();
    }
});
```

In Frame B, there is a JFXPanel which show PieChart.

The problem is when I closed it and reopen by clicking a button in Frame A, Frame B is shown but the Pie Chart won't show. (Frame B is DISPOSE_ON_CLOSED as DefaultCloseOperation)

Why is that and how to fix it?

Comment: I guess you haven't set [`Platform.setImplicitExit(false);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#setImplicitExit-boolean-), since this would prevent the shutdown of the JavaFX-Thread when the last JavaFX-window is closed.

Comment: Thanks guys! It works.